# How to set a property value similar to a field

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class, where I want to create multiple objects. 
Is there any way to create object as a property ?

```
public class UserandProfile
{
public Users_AboutMe objAMe = new Users_AboutMe();
public Users_Education objEdu = new Users_Education();
public Users_Interests objInterests = new Users_Interests();
}
```

Instead of this, how can I do something like this, here I want to add create obj also.

```
public class UserandProfile
{
 public Users_AboutMe objAMe { get; set; }
 public Users_Education objEdu { get; set; }
 public Users_Interests objInterests { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in C# 6 you are able to initialize an object directly in the property.

```
public Users_AboutMe objAMe { get; set; } = new Users_AboutMe();
```

If you are still on C# 5, it's probably best to just use a private variable to hold the object

```
private Users_AboutMe objAMe = new Users_AboutMe();

public Users_AboutMe ObjAMe {get { return objAMe; } set { objAMe = value;}}
```

As mentioned by @Belahcene Benzara Tahar, you can lazy load the private variable. There's a couple of scenarios where you might want to do that.

- If there is a chance that the variable will not be used at all (in
  which case you're wasting your time initializing it at the start).
- Offloading some of the initialization time cost for a later stage
  when it's actually needed.
- The class instance when instantiated holds
  some resources and you don't want to use/hold them until they are
  needed. Etc

To do that, you remove the instantiation line from the private variable declaration and place it inside the getter like this

```
private Users_AboutMe objAMe;  

public Users_AboutMe ObjAMe {
   get {
        if (objAMe == null) {
           objAMe =  new Users_AboutMe();
        }
        return objAMe;
   }
   set {
        objAMe = value;
    }
 }
```

This checks if objAMe

Comment: Well, sure, you can always initialize in the constructor or write out more complex getters and setters, but I just wanted to show a common pattern used to separate the property from the actual variable holding the value, which can then easily be extended as needed, etc.

Comment: You can lazy load your properties if they are heavy weight.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the properties in the Constructor.

```
public class UserandProfile
{
   // Properties
   public Users_AboutMe objAMe { get; set; }
   public Users_Education objEdu { get; set; }
   public Users_Interests objInterests { get; set; }

   // Constructor
   public UserandProfile()
   {
      objAMe = new Users_AboutMe();
      objEdu = new Users_Education();
      objInterests = new Users_Interests();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yup, i agree on this. If you are less then a C# 6